# Using OAuth 2.0 once and having that app keep going

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am going to be writing an app that uses the Google calendar API to pull data from a user's personal calendar, and I was wondering if there was a way to do this as like a one time thing, i.e. they will authorize access to their calendar and the user won't have to do that again and the app will keep getting to use the calendar. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline). When authorizing, you can obtain a refresh token along with it. Your refresh token can be used to obtain new access tokens for accessing calendar in this case. The refresh token does not expire and can be kept for future use.